# Turn off Database Diagrams in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-diagram

I use the keyboard arrow keys to navigate the SSMS Object Explorer, and when I expand a database, the first two items are Database Diagrams and Tables.

I usually want to get to Tables (or something below that).  Out of habit, I use the arrow keys to move down, and hitting Database Diagrams pops up a message asking me if I want to set up diagrams for the current database.

Anybody know a way to turn this thing off (in any version of SSMS)?  I rarely use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to type the letter 'T' to go straight to Tables.

I would be interested to know if you find a true solution.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, there is no way to edit standard Object Explorer tree in SQL Management Studio.